# Suggestions for running Festival TTS from Flex4 Adobe AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, mxml, festival

I'm trying to run [Festival text to speech](http://festvox.org/docs/manual-1.4.3/festival_7.html) from a AIR 2 app.

Here's a sample code for starting notepad

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="1024" height="768">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var exe:File = new File("c:/Windows/notepad.exe");
                var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = exe;
                var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
                args.push("e:/temp/Hello.txt");
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
                nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="265" y="236" label="Hello Button" width="465" height="131" fontSize="30" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The command that I want to run on the button click is here :

```
c:\FestivalTTS>echo "Hello world" | festival --tts
```

or start Festival like this:

```
c:\FestivalTTS>festival.exe --pipe
```

and then type the following in the Festival command prompt

```
(SayText "Hello world.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Read docs, they rule. You can communicate with process using [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)' standardInput and standardOutput. See [sample](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html).

Comment: how can I pipe commands in the NativeProcessStartupInfo  as c:\FestivalTTS>echo "Hello world" | festival --tts